# Can I use Philips Hue White Ambiance B27 Bulb for Apples Home Kit with every bulb fitting?

Tags: applications, homekit

I want buy a [Philips Hue White Ambiance B27 Bulb](http://www.apple.com/de/shop/product/HK5X2ZM/A/philips-hue-white-ambiance-b27-lampe) and want to know if I have to buy something special to use it or can I use it in any bulb fitting in my home?

I want it for my new borns room, so I can dim/turn off the light as soon as he sleeps.

PS: There is no Home-Kit tag at this stack avaible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will aslo need a Philips Hue Bridge. If you want to integrate it with  Apple HomeKit you need to have the newer bridge (square with round corners) and not the old one (circular).

Comment: And the new bulbs fit in my common bulb fitting?

Comment: Yes, it fits in a regular E27 socket.